# Flask doesn't seem to recognize file changes

Tags: python, flask

**A little background:**
I've been working on this project for about six months now and it's been running on Flask the whole time. Everything has been fine, multiple versions of the backend have been deployed live to support an app that's been in production for months now.

The development cycle involves writing everything locally and using Flask-Script's `runserver` command to test everything locally on `localhost:8080` before deploying to a dev server and then finally to the live server.

**The Problem:** The other day my local flask instance, which runs on `localhost:8080` apparently stopped respecting my local files.

I tried adding a new view (with a new template) and I got a 404 error when trying to view it in my browser.

I then tried making some test changes to one of the existing pages by adding a few extra words to the title. I restarted flask and none of those changes appeared.

I then went as far as deleting the entire `views.py` file. After restarting flask again, much to my dismay, I could still view the pages that were there originally (i.e. before this behavior started).

Finally, I made some changes to the `manage.py` file, which is where I put all of the Flask-Script commands, and they weren't recognized either. It's as if flask started reading from a cached version of the filesystem that won't update (which very well might be the case but I have no idea why it started doing this or how to fix the issue).

FYI: Browser caching shouldn't be an issue b/c I have the dev tools open with caching disabled. Plus the fact that changes to `manage.py` aren't being noticed shouldn't have anything to do with the browser.

Comment: what files are you refering as local files, .py files and templates or only .py files. Because to reload templates you have to pass those to run() command to watch.Try force refresh by adding some query string `http://urll?123`, or reload template and try clearing browser cache.

Comment: This is very suspicious. Are you sure that you are starting the local server at the correct directory and virtualenv? Have you tried starting flask directly (e.g. `python app.py`) with debug mode on?

Comment: What's inside your `manage.py` file? Are you sure you're telling the development server to use the reloader?

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 I'm referring to both templates and .py files. I first noticed the problem because of a change I made in `views.py` that wasn't being respected by the local flask server. Also, I explicitly add all of the files in `templates/` to the `runserver` command with the `extra_files` kwarg.

Answer (score 2):

You've most likely used flask in the DEBUG mode in which it auto reloads templates the app whenever a file changes.

Try using

```
export FLASK_DEBUG=True
```

before running

```
flask run
```

For more information see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#DEBUG

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue and deleting the `.pyc` files solved it for me.